# Custom Search Bar layout overlaps when app enter from background to foreground

Tags: swift, uikit, uisearchbar

```
class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar {
    private let toLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "To:"
        label.textColor = .label
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .medium)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configureUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configureUI()
    }

    private func configureUI() {
        self.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.searchTextField.clearButtonMode = .never
        self.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        self.setImage(UIImage(), for: .search, state: .normal)
        self.searchTextField.tokenBackgroundColor = UIColor.secondaryBackgroundColor
        self.tintColor = .label

        // Add "To:" label to the search bar
        self.addSubview(toLabel)
        toLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        toLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        // Set up the text field to start after the "To:" label
        self.searchTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(self.searchTextField)
        self.searchTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        self.searchTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
        self.searchTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // Adjust text field frame to prevent overlap with the "To:" label
        let textField = self.searchTextField
        let xValue = toLabel.frame.maxX + 8
        let width = self.frame.width - 12 - xValue - 12
        textField.frame = CGRect(x: xValue, y: textField.frame.minY, width: width, height: textField.frame.height)
    }
}
```

I created a custom search bar as above. The search bar text starts after `To:` Label. I added it as an outlet in `ViewController`. It works fine when the view is loaded, but when I move the app from background to foreground search bar text overlaps with `To:` Label.

I tried calling `viewWillLayoutSubview`, `searchBar.layoutSubviews()`, `searchBar.layoutIfNeeded()` in the `viewWillAppear` method. It didn't work. Can you suggest how to fix this?